# How to run QAC tool from command line?

Tags: qa-c

I have a C project and I would like to run QAC tool v7.0 from command line. I tried the following option,

```
C:\qac.exe -via <project_name.prj>
```

However, when I run the above command. I get an error saying the "VersionTag" is not found. The "VersionTag" string is the first line in the .prj file. I am not sure this is the right way to run this tool. Any help appreciated.

The qac -help is not giving valuable information either. The tool version is pretty old and the company 'Programming Research' behind this tool also has been renamed? to Perforce. They do not have any information about command line invocation either from the existing documentation or webpage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The QAC utility is the "engine" part of the QAC package, corresponding to a compiler.

It won't be happy being run on command line without a number of environment variables:

QACBIN must point to the bin directory of the QAC package installation;

QACHELPFILES must point to the location of message help files;

QACOUTPUT points to the location where output files will be generated (binary .err file for each source file and textual .met file containing semantic and metric information.

The -via parameter to the command line should point at a text file containing other parameters used by the utility.

The .prj file is a package-level file defining the location of C source files being analysed plus their configuration settings files, among other things. It definitely should not be passed directly as a parameter to the QAC utility.

This should get you started, and other questions need to be more specific.