# How to call Helix QAC from command line on Windows?

Tags: command-line, command

I am trying to find a way to trigger Helix QAC for a given C/C++ project using a batch script file, but I can't really find a command for that online. What would that command look like?

All I could find were some general guidelines [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53534494/how-to-run-qac-tool-from-command-line), but no concrete example.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Assuming project is setup and configured correctly,

[install]\common\bin\qacli analyze -cf -P [path-to-project_root] should do what you want.

The user manual is shipped with the product - [install]\common\doc_en-US.